# SyntaxError when adding and subtracting with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

When executing this basic query I have this error:

```
 WITH CALCULO AS (
   (SELECT SUM(UTILITY) FROM _coste_rv) - (SUM(UTILITY) + (SELECT SUM(UTILITY) FROM _tmp_coste)))
```

Message of Error:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "-"
```

What I want it to show is the amount of those 2 values

Comment: That is not a valid SQL query. It is not allowed to add values from different SELECT clauses.

Please, provide more information about the source data and what you are trying to achieve so that we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level statement should be SELECT. I.e. you cannot write

```
WITH Calculo AS (
   foo - bar
)
```

it should be

```
WITH Calculo AS (
   SELECT foo - bar as some_name
)
```

i.e.

```
WITH CALCULO AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(UTILITY) FROM _coste_rv) - 
    (SUM(UTILITY) + (SELECT SUM(UTILITY) FROM _tmp_coste))
        AS some_name
) 
SELECT ...
```

Comment: You are a teacher,
Thank you very much.